# El Capitan Terminal command to toggle clock between Analog and Digital?

Tags: macos

Is there a terminal command that will toggle between the Analog and Digital clock in the menu bar?

Can do it via point-and-click, but would like to incorporate it into a script that prepares my computer for recording screencasts.

Answer (score 1):

Make it analog: `defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog 1 && killall -KILL SystemUIServer`

Make it digital: `defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog 0 && killall -KILL SystemUIServer`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, set it up (`true/false`)

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog -bool true
```

Reset SystemUIServer for changes to take effect

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: remark : the reason I use true/false here is that's the same way how the OS set it via UI. Use `...IsAnalog YES/NO` or `...IsAnalog 1/0` you will still achieve same result :)

Comment: In Mac OS Ventura (13) you don't need to restart `SystemUIServer` for this change to take effect.